# Removing isolated point "hotspots" from big point sample

Tags: point, filter, heat-map, hot-spot, privacy

I have about 60000 points (lat, lng) that I want to layer on a world map as a heat map.
The problem is that there are some isolated point hotspots. Isolated here meaning they have only a few points around them.

Now, this map is going to be made publicly available and these points are user locations. Some users participating in this study leave the devices on and form those big hotspots. I want to preserve user privacy as much as I can even though every participant agreed to the terms of the study. Maybe those hotspots are user's houses (I have no idea) but I don't want to show the big hotspots that only have a few points near them.

I'm new to GIS and have been pointed to DBSCAN and HDBSCAN algorithms but I still can't seem to erase those hotspots.

Can someone maybe point me in the right direction?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: @BERA I was using geopandas and scikit-learn in python because I need the process so be automated as information is to be released every day. Not really GIS software per se but if you can recommend something that can do what I want I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Difficult to test without your data. I would also try clusterdbscan then drop clusters with < some point count